# Identity not working in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have created a .NET Core project without identity and then attempted to add an identity from scaffold. My code in startup is:

```
public System.IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectDbContext>();

    ...
}
```

But when calling the identity form it is not working and header URL is:

> http://localhost:5000/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FLogin

What am I missing?

Comment: Ping me if the linked solution doesn't resolve this, but it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem exactly ,but if you want to add Identity manually maybe this code will work for you just put it inside ConfigureService on Startup class :

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(options => 
             option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And make sure that your `ProjectDbContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext` ,
 and for your `ApplicationUser` if you want you can use `IdentityUser` instead or you  can customize your `ApplicationUser` by inheriting from `IdentityUser` ,and on these two way don't add any `DbSet` to `ProjectDbContext` ,Asp Core Identity will add this for you.